# Social sign in Android/iPhone app with server side

Tags: android, ios, facebook-access-token, hybridauth, socialauth

I'm evaluating HybridAuth and socialAuth-android, but I'm not restricted to those platforms only. Till now I only read the documentation of the 2 libraries and didn't play with the code itself.

**The requirements:**

1. Letting the user, through an Android/iPhone app, giving permission to gather some data from his profile/s (Facebook, Twitter, Linkedin...). Should act as the standard user experience. If it's possible the user should not enter his username and password of his profile. I thought of using the sign-in API, even that the user is not actually signing in to my app with those profiles.
2. The server should be able to gather the information from time to time from the different profiles that the user gave access to.

I prefer using only one library to accomplish my needs, but from reading the HybridAuth and socialAuth-android, it looks that it won't going to work.

**I thought of doing the following** (still not sure if it can be done)

1. Use the socialAuth-android on the Android app, and asking the user for permission
2. Sending the token from the Android app to the server.
3. On the server using the [HybridAuto Sessions](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/HybridAuth_Sessions.html) 'restoreSessionData'. This is the tricky part, since the restore session is looking for the serialized array from 'getSessionData'. I thought on looking on the array and to try constructing it by myself from the information I can gather from the socialAuth-android.

**And the question:**

1. Did I miss anything? can it be done only by one library?
2. If you have better recommendations for other libraries, it would be great to hear about.
3. Would I be able to implement my thoughts, or the data between the 2 libraries is too different to achieve this, at the end of the day I believe that we are talking mainly on access token, so at first glance it looks doable.
4. If you have better practices to achieve it, I'll be glad to hear.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this question warrants opinion-based answers. @nheimann1 is very clearly asking for best-practices and feature specification from developers with experience regarding an area of app/web development which is shrouded with poor/security-lacking practices and a plethora of solutions which serve completely different purposes. Please re-open.